# Getting the least significant String

Tags: java, string, parsing

Having a list of strings like "SDCVisual", "SDCRoller", "SDCGame" how could I get in an efficient way the common part of these Strings ("SDC") ?

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Longest common prefix for n string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578349/longest-common-prefix-for-n-string)

Comment: Does that part need to be their common prefix? What is the max number of strings you are going to have?

Comment: You show an example of how the strings start, what if the strings were "Java for you", "Teach Java" and "More Java for me", would the common part be "Java"?

Comment: If you are looking for a prefixes, it was just asked yesterday. If it is not always a prefix - I withdraw my dupe claim.

Comment: My apologies, I see now that the question was asked yesterday. Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's always a prefix you could use Commons StringUtils `getCommonPrefix` method:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html