# Finding longest common prefix in a ternary search tree

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dictionary, data-structures, ternary-search-tree

I implement a ternary search tree for a 20000 words.I want to know an algorithm to find a longest common prefix(prefix that is shared by at least 2 words)?
Is there anyway to find a Longest Common Prefix in a tree?(without ternary search tree)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Longest common prefix for n string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578349/longest-common-prefix-for-n-string)

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy solution and it is linear complexity, You know that  [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) is a string matching algorithm that uses hashing to do that. The ideea is to create a hash table. You go through all the words and at each length 1, 2, .. len( word ) you put the key( the hash value for that substring )  in the table , and when you already have that key in the table that means you have 2 words ( at least ) with that hash value. Then you only need to find the longest index that has that property.