# sum of LCP of all pairs of substrings of a given string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, suffix-array

How to find the sum of length of Longest Common Prefixes of all pairs of substrings of a given string.
For eg answer for string "aba" is 8.
|s|<=1e5.

Comment: LCP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578349/longest-common-prefix-for-n-string and the rest would seem trivial. Finding all substrings. Although what do you mean by "sum" the LCP? Multiply its length by how many times it appears? I guess that means it matters that there are two equally long longest common prefixes.

Comment: sum is adding the length of LCP.

Comment: why is it 8 for "aba"?

Comment: LCP is 2. It's a tie between "ab" and "ba".  Four different substrings have one of those prefixes. I've never been good with trie's -- can you put a reference count on the trie nodes? That would really make all the twists in this question trivial changes to longest common prefix (which is already answered).